# Setting Xcode breakpoint by code? (like pause() function)

Tags: xcode, debugging, execution

I'm finding a way pausing program execution by code on Xcode
As an example, I can stop execution with `abort()` C function. This pops Xcode debugger up.

However, this exits program completely, so I'm finding a way to **pause** execution. So I can resume execution after checking execution states.

This is required for handling light-weight errors. I tried `pause()` C function, but it doesn't work. The execution aborted instead of pausing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to be able to break on a specific function whenever there's an error, then define a function like so:

```
void BREAK_HERE_Eonil(void) {
    NSLog(@"Set a breakpoint on BREAK_HERE_Eonil to debug.\n");
}
```

Call `BREAK_HERE_Eonil()` whenever you would like to enter the debugger. Set a breakpoint on `BREAK_HERE_Eonil()` in Xcode. Now, run under the debugger. Whenever you hit this function, you'll break into the debugger.

You might also be able to use the old `Debugger()` call; Xcode has an option under the Run menu to "Stop on Debugger()/DebugStr()".

You can also just run your app under the debugger and hit the big pause button in the debugger window whenever you want to break in.

Comment: Brilliant technique! Thanks for answer!

Answer (score 1):

Another method I often use in iOS programming is to include a breakpoint in an if statement. Like so:

```
if (your_condition) {

   //put an Xcode breakpoint here

}
```

That way I can conditionally call breakpoints in loops and other places that get called too often to have an unconditional breakpoint.

Comment: You can also right click the breakpoint, click edit breakpoint and add a condition there.